# Older Location service & updated GCM push in android

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, google-play-services, android-gradle-plugin, location-services

Im using depricated version of location service

```
   public class UserLocation implements LocationListener, GooglePlayServicesClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GooglePlayServicesClient.OnConnectionFailedListener
```

updated version of GCM push

```
    extends GcmListenerService
```

gradle is as follows

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:6.5.87'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:7.5.0'
```

But unable to sync project receive some errors like

Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.

> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugCompile'.
>   Could not find com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:6.5.87build.gra.
>        Searched in the following locations:
>            https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/android/gms/play-services-location/6.5.87build.gra/play-services-location-6.5.87build.gra.pom
>            https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/android/gms/play-services-location/6.5.87build.gra/play-services-location-6.5.87build.gra.jar
>                 Required by:
>            incidentchanger:app:unspecified

Comment: You should use the same play services version for both location and gcm. So you should use 7.5.0 for the location service, or the newest one 7.8.0

Comment: @ztan location serivice 7.5.0 will provide fused location i dont want to use that. i want **LocationClient** with **GCMListenerService**

Comment: Is there a reason that you are continuing to use play-services-location:6.5? Why not use v7.8.0 for both gcm and location?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Didn't found any alternative to make it work, finally updated location api and related code
Thanks Stackoverflow :)